# Data structure most suitable for finding the minimal value

Tags: c++, data-structures

What is the most suitable data-structure for holding a set of pairs `(k,v)` where I have to do the same amount of updates to `v` as the amount of finding the element with least `v`?

I was thinking about keeping them in a `map<pair<k,v>>` and to find the pair with minimal `v` each time I inset a new pair (the amount of additions is very small...).

Each time I will update the `v` I will compare it the "minimal" pair, and if it is smaller I will update the "minimal" pair.

I there a better solution to this?

Comment: Does v always increase ? or can its value decrease?

Comment: `v` could also decrease - it represents a running average of some sort...

Comment: @HarshilSharma `std::map` are sorted automatically!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution only takes into account the situation where a new value becomes lower than the older minimum value.
It will fail if the older minimum value increases, and you have to find the new minimum.

Well I would keep 2 maps:

```
map<k,v> kKeyMap;

multimap<v,&k> vValueMap;
```

Use the multimap to get the lowest value (because it can handle multiple k's with the same v).
Like regular map, it's sorted, so acquiring the lowest is just a matter of getting the first item in the map **O(1)**.

On each change, you look up the **k** with the first map (`kKeyMap`), and change the value **O(logn)**.
Use the old **v** value to remove the old (v,k) value from the multimap, then add then new (v,k) value. **O(logn)**

So, you have O(1) query for lowest, and O(logn) for insert. Assuming n = #k